# Monotocity of a trace function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Define a function on the space of n-dimensional positive definite matrices:
$$
f(X)=tr(X^{-1}-(X+M)^{-1})， X>0, M>0\text{ a constant matrix}.
$$
prove that $f$ is monotonous, i.e. 
$$
X\geq Y>0 \Rightarrow f(X)\leq f(Y)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim does **not** hold. For it to hold, we should have $\nabla f(X) \le 0$ (in Löwner ordering). That is,
\begin{equation*}
 (X+M)^{-2}-X^{-2} \ge 0,
\end{equation*}
should hold for all $X>0$.

Take for example the strictly positive definite matrices:

\begin{equation*}
 X = \begin{bmatrix}17 & -18\\ -18 & 45 \end{bmatrix},\qquad M =\begin{bmatrix}29 & -17\\-17 & 10\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Then, $(X+M)^{-2}-X^{-2}$ is a matrix will all entries negative (elementwise), hence it not positive definite.

Comment: Is there a sign error here? In the one-dimensional case, $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+m}=\frac{m}{x(x+m)},$$ which is monotone decreasing for $x>0$, and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(x+m)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is negative, i.e. not positive.

Comment: @Michael: no, it is not a sign error; the problem is that the map $X \mapsto X^2$ is not operator monotone; in fact the above $X$ and $M$ lead to $(X+M)^{-2}-X^{-2}$ being an *indefinite* matrix, so neither $\uparrow$ nor $\downarrow$ can hold for the original function.

Comment: @Suvrit:I get your point, but I guess what Michael says is you should really say
$$
(X+M)^{-2}-X^{-2}\leq 0
$$
does not hold.

Comment: But I did say that, in words instead of as a symbol: "...hence it is not positive definite" :-)